# Fourier Cosine expansion of $\sin x$

Tags: trigonometry, partial-differential-equations, fourier-series

Instructor mentioned something in class that got me thinking...

Why is it possible for $\sin x$ to have a Fourier Cosine expansion in $[0, \pi]$? It seems strange to me that you're able to express $\sin x$ as an infinite sum of cosines. Maybe I'm just missing the (perhaps very obvious) point here.

Comment: The function you are effectively expanding is the function $f$ which coincides with $\sin$ on $[0,\pi]$, and which coincides with $-\sin$ on $[-\pi,0]$. Then you make a $2\pi$-periodic function with this one. The expanded function has the parity of $\cos$.

Comment: Putting it another way, if you start with $\sin$ on the interval $[0,\pi]$ and extend it periodically, with period $\pi$, then the result is $|\sin(x)|$, which is an even function, hence its Fourier series has only cosine terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A picture is worth a thousand words :

Red curve : $y_1=\sin(x)$

Blue curve : $\quad y_2=\frac{2}{\pi}-\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{\cos{n\pi}+1}{n^2-1}\cos(nx) \quad$ : Fourier cosine expansion of $y_1$ on $[0,\pi]$.

$y_1=y_2$ on the range of definition $[0,\pi]$.

Outside this range, $y_2$ is the periodic repetition of the pattern defined on $[0,\pi]$.

[image]

Since $\cos(n\pi)+1=(-1)^n+1$ is null for odd $n$ ,$\quad y_2=\frac{2}{\pi}-\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{4\:k^2-1}\cos(2kx) \quad$

OTHER EXAMPLE :

Fourier cosine series of $\sin(x)$ with range of definition $[0,\frac{2\pi}{3}]$ :
[image]